# ElementClickInterceptedException for https://health.usnews.com/doctors/; Not Clicking the Button

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm trying to mine href data from doctors profiles on the page https://health.usnews.com/doctors/new-jersey. My code is using Selenium to host a web server to accesses the website and mine the URLs, doing the heavy lifting for the web scraping. My code successfully pulls the data and puts it into a set to avoid duplicates, but is not able to move onto the next page. When the program runs, it either loops respectively or closes outright. Here is a screenshot of the website when it attempts to click the button and fails. Description states the possible errors this stems from:

[[10620:16572:0228/204556.116:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(192)] [20:45:56.116] USB: usb_service_win.cc:105 SetupDiGetDeviceProperty({{A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0}, 6}) failed: Element not found. (0x490)
[11692:2400:0228/204600.897:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(970)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ss9u.png)

I'm getting an ElementClickInterceptedException that reads as follows:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button title="Next Page" data-page="2" class="page-numbers__Button-sc-138ov1k-4 page-numbers__NextButton-sc-138ov1k-6 
biGwcb hoTHNb"></button> is not clickable at point (456, 865). Other element would receive the click: <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://8305b9cc4359dda504fe47652a5a9af6.safeframe.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-40/html/container.html" id="google_ads_iframe_/4020/usn.health/healthcare/doctors/search/newjersey_1" title="3rd party ad content" name="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="320" height="50" data-is-safeframe="true" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" aria-label="Advertisement" tabindex="0" data-google-container-id="2" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-load-complete="true"></iframe>
  (Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.70)
```

Here is my section of the code that handles these issues (It's probably pretty messy since it's my first time using Selenium!):

```
def getPageHLinks(url, count, tempSet, driver):

    junkLinks = ['https://www.usnews.com/features/info/privacy/state-notice',
                 'https://www.usnews.com/features/info/privacy'
                 ]
    try:
        # Extract the page's HTML
        doctors_HLinks_Set = tempSet  # Place hrefs into a set to remove duplicates
        doctors_HLinks = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='Anchor-byh49a-0 eMEqFO']")

        for doctors_HLink in doctors_HLinks:
            if doctors_HLink in junkLinks:  # Removal clause for a useless link
                continue
            doctors_HLinks_Set.add(doctors_HLink.get_attribute('href'))

        print(doctors_HLinks_Set)

       
        if count != 51:  # Page iteration automation, starts at page 2
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

            try:
                button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title = 'Next Page' and @class= 'page-numbers__Button-sc-138ov1k-4 page-numbers__NextButton-sc-138ov1k-6 biGwcb hoTHNb']")))
                ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).perform()

                time.sleep(5)

                button.click() # Click the button 
                count += 1
                return getPageHLinks(url, count, doctors_HLinks_Set, driver)
            
            except ElementClickInterceptedException as e:
                print(f"ElementClickInterceptedException: {e}")
                driver.quit()
                return doctors_HLinks_Set
            
        else:  # Reached page 50, search is complete so output the data
            driver.quit()
            return doctors_HLinks_Set
        
    except NoSuchWindowException as e:
        print(f"No such window: {e}")
        driver.quit()
        return tempSet
```

I have tried multiple solutions to this problem:

- Adding a wait timer to see if the ad times out (Didn't work)
- Adding an adblocker extension into the chromedriver to remove the ad (This didn't work, iframe with the ad still popped up)
- used an ActionChain command to scroll down to the bottom of the page to click the button (Button isn't dynamically generated, so that wasn't the issue)

Nothing has seemed to work.

Edit:
These are the errors I found when accessing the HTML Console on the website:
[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gXAV.png)

Comment: Are you able to dismiss the ad and click on the desired element when you visit the site as a human?  If so, why can't you just do the same thing in selenium?

Comment: When I delete the ad, it just infinitely loops while the webpage says, ""We're sorry, there was a problem loading search results. Retry" like in Image1. I can code up a fix for it, but it looks like the adblocker I installed on Chromedriver gets rid of it after I delete it and the error goes away.

Comment: I would add a sleep after button.click().  If the dom is updated via JS, Selenium won't wait before you use find_elements again and you could have some stale element exceptions being thrown.  For your initial problem, it seems that google ad iframe is overlaying the button.  Not sure why that is, but if you can click to close the ad, do that before trying to click the next button.  It may be that the DOM is in the middle of making some changes and a sort of in between state causes the overlap.  A sleep before attempting to click/get the button element may help there too.

Comment: You should also remove this:  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).perform() ... that's not necessary, and might be causing some of the unwanted behavior.  (scrolling possibly?)  The driver doesn't know when a scroll is complete, and it may be attempting two at a similar time... (scroll to move to element, and scroll to move element into view when .click() is used...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use backend API to extract the required details instead of selenium. This is efficient and faster way to get the data and you can avoid duplicates as well

**API:** https://health.usnews.com/health-care/doctors/search-data?distance=in-state&location=New%20Jersey&page_num=2

1. Fetch the above API and extract doctors details
2. Change the page_num in the API and fetch it to get more details
3. You can continue the same in a loop unilt hasNextPage true

If you wish to continue only with selenium then you can follow another approach. Frame the pagination urls and fetch them individually. You can find the code snippet for the same.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

def initialize_driver():
    # Specify the path to the downloaded ChromeDriver executable
    chrome_driver_path = r'path_to_driver'

    # Initialize Chrome browser with the correct argument
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Add any other options if needed
    chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'

    # Specify the path to the ChromeDriver executable using the service argument
    chrome_service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(chrome_driver_path)

    # Initialize Chrome browser with the service
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
    return driver


def getDoctorHLinks(url,tempSet):
    # Initialize selenium driver
    driver = initialize_driver()
    # Fetch the URL
    driver.get(url)
    # Wait for some time to load
    time.sleep(3)

    junkLinks = ['https://www.usnews.com/features/info/privacy/state-notice',
                    'https://www.usnews.com/features/info/privacy',
                    'https://www.usnews.com/info/features/terms'
                    ]
    # Extract the page's HTML
    doctors_HLinks_Set = tempSet  # Place hrefs into a set to remove duplicates
    doctors_HLinks = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='Anchor-byh49a-0 eMEqFO']")
    
    for doctors_HLink in doctors_HLinks:
        link = doctors_HLink.get_attribute('href')
        if link in junkLinks:  # Removal clause for a useless link
                continue
        doctors_HLinks_Set.add(link)

    print(doctors_HLinks_Set)

    # Close selenium driver
    driver.quit()
    # Wait for few secs before initializing a new driver
    time.sleep(2)

tempSet = set({})
page = 1
final_page = 50
while page <= final_page:
    url = f"https://health.usnews.com/doctors/new-jersey?page_num={page}"
    # Get all the Doctor Links
    getDoctorHLinks(url, tempSet)
    page += 1

print(tempSet)
```